# Changing a url depending on what link chosen (HTML) no asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, getjson

**TLDR** I need to change a javascript variable on the same page after clicking a link (can be from a different page) so that the getjson request pulls different data without having to duplicate on html pages.

---

I am using some getJSON requests with Jquery, to make calls to populate my pages.
I want to be able to (in plain HTML / javascript) when the user clicks say "link 1" or "link 2" to open the same page (say page.html) but change the get request url to "link 1" or "link 2".

Page.html

```
var url = ??;    
$.getJSON(url, function(data){}
```

link 1

```
var url = host/link1
<a href="page.html">link1</a>
```

link2

```
var url = host/link2
<a href="page.html">link2</a>
```

So I call the same page but am able to populate it with different content.
Purposely staying away from asp. Was thinking maybe of inserting the content into a div after page load so the url can be set or something along those lines.

**Edit1** I also need to redo the getjson request after "page.html" loads and re run it every second. I have done this with other pages but not in the case where I need to pull on data depending on a link that is automatically generated.

**Edit2** Decided to go with the Cookie approach using jquery and jquery cookie as it seemed most reasonable. See thread [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756422/setting-a-cookie-based-on-the-name-of-the-link-that-is-clicked)

<s>Any ideas how I might go about this?</s>

Comment: Am currently thinking about looking into jquery cookie. To hold the URL? So if any ideas on doing this way as well would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a[href=page.html]').click(function()
{
  $.getJSON('host/' + $(this).text(), function(data){});
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Not having any luck with this. I need it to populate the data after the page.html loads. Also I'll add above I am going to need it to run the getjson request every second after the pages loads.

Comment: If you need to do it repeatedly, you'll have to either modify the loaded page's DOM (you can do this with an iframe or popup), or use cookies (but then what if you click two different links in succession?).  I actually think using a get parameter (I realize this requires server-side code) is the cleanest solution.

Comment: Can't use server side :(. I realise how much easier it would be. Either I do it with cookies or such or face using "page1" "page2" "page3". Going to try something along the lines of (this) to cookie then 
cookievalue = var x = readCookie('cookiename')
url = 'http://' + host + cookeivalue;

Comment: Again thanks for the help always get you answering my questions :D