# jQuery cookie, not saving on link click

Tags: jquery, cookies

So I'm using [carhartl's jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) in order to keep the open states of my side menu. However when I click on a link within the side menu, the cookie is set *until I click on a link on the side menu and the page is refreshed* in which it then resets to the previous set cookie.

This still does not work EVEN IF the default action of the link is disabled and is navigated afterwards like below answer to [Setting a cookie based on the name of the link that is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756422/setting-a-cookie-based-on-the-name-of-the-link-that-is-clicked)

My code that sets and reads the cookie

```
//Side menu sliding
$("#MainMenu > ul li").click(function () {

    //stop sliding event for parent(s) of clicked list item
    $(this).parent().click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    //Slide up or down
    $(this).children("ul").eq(0).slideToggle("fast");
    $(this).toggleClass("closed");

    $("#MainMenu > ul li").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
    });
    $(this).addClass("selected");

    // Cookies
    createOpenedCookie();
    createSelectedCookie();


    var link = $(this).find("a").eq(0);
    if (link.length > 0) {
        window.location.href = $(link).attr("rel");
    }

});

//selected
function createSelectedCookie() {
    var selected = 0;
    $("#MainMenu > ul").find("ul, li").each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            selected = i;
        }
    });

    $.cookie("selected", selected, { expires: 7 });
    alert(selected);
}
```

EDIT:

Setting timeouts to the cookies has *no effect*

EDIT 2: It seems that it only resets to a previous cookie if the cookies sub directory (link) is different to that of the original clicked. This is probably some weird behavior specifically to do with the loading / redirecting of C# .net pages (.cshtml extension). I will post an answer if I figure it out.

Comment: How are you setting the cookie? Please add the code.

Comment: @ChiMo - you still haven't shown the code which _sets_ the cookie...

Comment: Edited, hope it clarifies it a little

Comment: Is any cookie manipulation is being done on page refresh??? From your question, i understood that, based on link click in side menu cookie is saved. When page refresh, side menu displays with the help of last saved cookie value...

Comment: Just check that, is any double click or cookie manipulation is being  on page refresh...

Comment: Hrmm there is no double clicking - and as far as I can see it should work fine. It is just when I click on an element with a different directory that it doesnt work. (eg /subdir/page.html from page /subdir/currentpage.html works but /othersubdir/otherpage.html from /subdir/currentpage.html does not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are only set and read relative to the directory they are set on - therefore cookies needed to be set within *root* or the *parent path*.

```
$.cookie("name", value, { path: "/" });
```

[jquery cookie not working - same domain different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22219815/4048628)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `$.cookie(name,value)`, cookie is set with no expire time which means it is removed at end of session (when browser closes). Once browser is closed, session cookies are cleared.

If you want cookies to be available even browser is closed, set an expiration date as shown in the [readme](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/README.md):

```
$.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });
```

Comment: This seems like the correct answer except that the OP claims the cookie is not present upon _page reload_. He does not mention closing the browser. I suspect the problem is being described improperly and that you are correct, but clarification should be made with the OP.

Comment: This does not affect the behavior of the problem whatsoever

Comment: From earlier question, i mistakenly understood that cookie is getting expired on page refresh because of expiration time.. It seems that actual problem cookie value is reset to default one whenever page refresh...